# Robin boundary conditions

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, elliptic-equations

Consider the PDE $Lu = 0$ in the upper half plane, where $L$ is a second order elliptic differential operator. On $y=0$, we give it the boundary condition $a u + b \frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu} = 0$, where $\nu$ is the inwards pointing unit normal vector.

My question is, is there a standard way of extending $u$ in a tubular neighborhood of the $x$-axis, that is, converting the problem to a PDE without boundary? If the boundary condition were Dirichlet/Neumann, we could do so by taking the odd/even extension in the $y$-variable, for example. But I am unsure about the general Robin conditions.

Comment: A reference for "Robin conditions" ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Looked at a few, but not finding anything reasonable. I would be very grateful if you could point to one.

Comment: It is doable but it is more challenging than homogeneous Dirichlet and Neuman Boundary Conditions. You can follow section 2.2.3 of this document: https://www.studocu.com/en/document/technische-universiteit-delft/structural-dynamics/lecture-notes/lecture-notes-and-exercises-on-wave-dynamics-of-structures/1377306/view